# How can I use the Pingdom API to pause and resume checks from bash?

Tags: pingdom

I'm writing a quick and dirty deployment script and would like to disable and reenable a Pingdom check as part of it. How do I do that using something like cURL?

Answer (score 5):

To pause a check:

```
 curl -X PUT -u 'your@email:yourpassword' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'App-Key: yourapplicationkey' -d 'paused=true' https://api.pingdom.com/api/2.0/checks/checkid
```

To resume a check:

```
 curl -X PUT -u 'your@email:yourpassword' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'App-Key: yourapplicationkey' -d 'paused=false' https://api.pingdom.com/api/2.0/checks/checkid
```

- Replace your@email with your pingdom email.
- Replace yourpassword with your pingdom password.
- Replace yourapplicationkey with a generated key from the "Sharing" section in your account.
- Replace checkid with the numeric ID you see in the browser URL when you click on your check in the Pingdom UI.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use modern way - just API key instead of using also email/password.
First, generate your own API key in https://my.pingdom.com/app/api-tokens and then you can use `curl` commands like for pausing:

```
curl -X PUT \
  https://api.pingdom.com/api/3.1/checks \
  -H 'Authorization:Bearer YOURAPIKEY' \  
  -d 'paused=true&checkids=777'
```

or for resuming:

```
curl -X PUT \
  https://api.pingdom.com/api/3.1/checks \
  -H 'Authorization:Bearer YOURAPIKEY' \  
  -d 'paused=false&checkids=777'
```

Replace `YOURAPIKEY` with your real API key and `777` with valid check ID.
`checkids` can be also omitted, then all checks will be modified.